# Nominal form or adjectival form?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, attributive-nouns, derivational-morphology

Given that the adjectival form of *wood* is *wooden*,  why has *wood* been used instead of *wooden* in the following sentence?

- *It is a spacious house with wood floor.*

Comment: Similar to "brick walls" which are not called "bricked walls" and is a [**noun adjunct**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) such as *chicken soup*.

Comment: Is it correct if I say wooden floor? If yes, what is the difference between wooden floor and wood floor?

Comment: @Shorecoral yes, wooden floor is more appropriate when you mean it in a general sense, Wood would be more appropriate if you used to describe it with another noun like  maple wood flooring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is different between the usage noun and adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/486054/what-is-different-between-the-usage-noun-and-adjective)